# opencv combine 2 images with offset in y dirrection

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I have the following code to display 2 images next to eachother with a slight offset both over the x dirrection(spacing) and the y dirrection(yoffset):

```
void output(Mat left, Mat right) {
    Mat imgResult(left.rows + abs(yoffset), right.cols + left.cols + spacing,
            left.type());

    Mat roiImgResult_Left = imgResult(Rect(0, 0, left.cols, left.rows));
    Mat roiImgResult_Right = imgResult(
            Rect(left.cols + spacing, 0, right.cols, right.rows+yoffset));

    Mat roiImg1 = left(Rect(0, 0, left.cols, left.rows));
    Mat roiImg2 = right(Rect(0, 0, right.cols, right.rows+yoffset));
    //Mat roiImg  = Rect(0,0,spacing,right.rows);

    roiImg1.copyTo(roiImgResult_Left); //Img1 will be on the left of imgResult
    roiImg2.copyTo(roiImgResult_Right); //Img2 will be on the right of imgResult
    resize(imgResult, imgResult, imagesize);
    imshow("Final imgage", imgResult);
    cv::moveWindow("Final imgage", screenx, screeny);
}
```

The critical point is the yoffset which I cannot seem to get to work, the current version gives a

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file /home/thijs/Desktop/opencv-2.4.9/Install-OpenCV/Ubuntu/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 323
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/thijs/Desktop/opencv-2.4.9/Install-OpenCV/Ubuntu/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:323: error: (-215) 0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows in function Mat
```

error. If I remove the +yoffset from `Mat roiImg2 = right(Rect(0, 0, right.cols, right.rows+yoffset));` it will not give me an exception but the resulting image looks really weird. Anybody got any experience with this?

So in somewhat immages this is what the code does:

```
_______
|      |              ^ yoffset 
|left  |   ______     v
|______|   |right|
           |_____|
        <-> spacing
```

all of this in just one window(don't care what is in the rest so that is just random data that was in memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception says that the specified ROI spans beyond the image boundaries.

I think you have a typo on these lines:

```
Mat roiImgResult_Right = imgResult(Rect(left.cols + spacing, 0, right.cols, right.rows+yoffset));
...
Mat roiImg2 = right(Rect(0, 0, right.cols, right.rows+yoffset));
```

Assuming `yoffset` is positive, you should have the following:

```
Mat roiImgResult_Right = imgResult(Rect(left.cols + spacing, yoffset, right.cols, right.rows));
...
Mat roiImg2 = right(Rect(0, 0, right.cols, right.rows));
```

If negative `yoffset` are to be expected, the appropriate code would be a little more complex (as you would have to crop the right image *or* shift the left one).